# WP7 ProgressBar breaks when Value exceeds Minimum or Maximum value

Tags: windows-phone-7, progress-bar

The visual aspect of the WP7 ProgressBar stops working when the Value exceeds the Minimum or Maximum. Specifically, when the minimum or maximum is exceeded and then the Value later returns to a value between Min and Max, the ProgressBar is either stuck at completely dark or completely filled (for Min and Max, respectively.)

Here's my test code if any of you are interested in reproducing this. How do I work around this?

Btw, I should add that my Minimum and Maximum vary and the Value naturally exceeds these values sometimes.

XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="150" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">Up</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Width="150" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Down</Button>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBar" Value="{Binding Progress}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"></ProgressBar>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        Maximum = 100;
    }

    private int _progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Progress");
        }
    }

    private int _maximum;
    public int Maximum
    {
        get { return _maximum; }
        set
        {
            _maximum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Maximum");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Progress += 10;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Progress -= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I ended up modifying my DomainModel slightly so that my XAML binds to a different Property that checks to see if the Min and Max are exceeded and if they are, return only the Min or Max. That said, this is still an annoying bug, IMHO.

Comment: You could try the PerformanceProgressBar out of the Silverlight tools for windows phone. It might work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here, per my comment above. The answer I ended up going with was:

"Modifying my DomainModel slightly so that my XAML binds to a different Property that checks to see if the Min and Max are exceeded and if they are, return only the Min or Max."